# Get json with headers by using nodejs

Tags: json, node.js

How can I get objects from JSON with headers and send an HTTP get a request to a link?

`setHeader('header1', 'header1_value') for http://getsomejson.com/json.php` 
and retrieve data then send them to

```
randomlinktosenddata.com
```

Comment: json objects don't have headers...

Comment: Basically you're trying to send a HTTP request to http://getsomejson.com/json.php (and setting a couple of headers in said request) ?

Comment: yes, thats what i wanna do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like request

try this code:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'http://getsomejson.com/json.php ',
    headers: {
        'Some-header': 'header-value'
    }
};

request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        // use data

        request({url:'randomlinktosenddata.com'} , (error,response,body) => {
            // do more stuff...
        });
    }
});
```

you can install the request library by doing `npm install request`

Check this link: https://github.com/request/request

hope this helps

Comment: So can i do the same thing to set headers to randomlinktosenddata.com

Comment: Exactly. The first argument of the `request` function is the options object. In the randomlinktosenddata.com request options object you could add a "headers" object just like in the first request

Comment: Thank you so much.